# Is there a way to get the path of a File with "/" instead of "\"?

Tags: java

I am making an HTTP Server in Java so that (on start) it finds all files in a directory (and it's sub-directories) and adds them to the server. But when getting the path of a file and trying to give it to HttpServer.createContext(), it throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal value for path or protocol`. (with the string argument, say "\folder/index.html"). To get this value, I used

```
file.getParent().substring(24) + "/" + file.getName()
```

I used substring because I had to exclude the folder the web server is in. The illegal character is the backslash. I have tried extending File to change `separator` and `separatorChar`, but that only created 2 new variables. While using String.replace() didn't seem to have any effect. Is there a different method than `File.getParent` or `File.getPath` that I can use, or is there a way to use `String.replace` that I am not seeing?

EDIT:
String.replace() seems to be the best answer... But I am not completely sure how to use it.

EDIT 2: For some reason the backslash isn't showing up, so I changed it.

Comment: You being a Java Pro should check what the `Paths` class has to offer as far as path splitting and processing is concerned

Comment: @Marged Ok, I will. Also, "JAVAPRO" is a relative term.

Comment: But you know that `String.replace()` doesn't change the original string but returns the manipulated string as a result?

Comment: @vanje I tried `(file.getParent().substring(24) + "/" + file.getName()).replace("\\\'", "/")` as an argument to the method that creates a http server context. Am I doing it right? I do realize that "\\\'" may be incorrect...

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the java [System.getProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Notice that, in this context, `"file.separator"` is a **key** which we are
using to `get` this property from current system executing the java VM.

Insteady of using a slash (<kbd>/</kbd>), you should choose a  platform agnostic file separator, as an example it should be:

```
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    System.out.println(separator);
    // unix / , windows \
```

Comment: But I have to use `/`, because that is the only thing the HttpServer will accept.  Is it a terrible idea to set the system property with System.setProperty()? Or will that break my computer?

Comment: this occurs because the file separator is a operacional system primitive, it is not a default value for all operational system. (linux, windows, macos etc.)

Comment: But I need it different in my String, what should I do?

Comment: You need to use system.getProperty. So it will work for any operational system. If you need different, you can use a Object to define this behaviour. Let's say you have a aliasPath and a realPath. Where the real path will load the correct `path` from file system.

Comment: @anygenergicJAVAPRO Files are very different from URLs. They have different rules.

Comment: @Danizavtz I know what the default character is! How do I change it in my String!?

Comment: @NomadMaker I know that Files are different from URLs, that is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Paths.get(...)`

Try `Paths.get(".")` // current working directory.

Or tell it, on which path it should start:

Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, for current loged in user, home directory.
String pathStr = "/";

`Path homeDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`

Getting from the user directory into the data directory: `homeDir.get("data")`

```
Path dataPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File dataFile = dataPath.toFile();
```

Now use operations on dataFile, to check what files and directories there are, on that location of the file system.